# Need Nan keys:value when writing out PySpark DF as Json

Tags: json, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to write out a PySpark DataFrame (DF) in JSON format. The DF has some rows with NAN values. I am using the following approach to write out the DF

```
DF.coalesce(1).write.format('json').mode('overwrite').save('myDest/' + ext)
```

The output JSON ignores keys where values are none.

This is an example:

```
{"id":"890226","dt":"2018-01 14T17:05:00.000Z","key":2.9427571,"anotherkey":3}
{"id":"890226","dt":"2018-01-14T17:10:00.000Z","key":2.9815376,"anotherkey":3}
{"id":"890226","dt":"2018-01-14T17:15:00.000Z","key":2.94226,"anotherkey":3}
{"id":"890226","dt":"2018-01-14T17:20:00.000Z","anotherkey":1}
{"id":"890226","dt":"2018-01-14T17:25:00.000Z","anotherkey":1}
{"id":"890226","dt":"2018-01-14T17:30:00.000Z","anotherkey":1}
{"id":"890226","dt":"2018-01-14T17:35:00.000Z","anotherkey":1}
```

as shown in the last 4 roes, the resulting JSON skips the 'key' attribute because in the DF it has a value of NAN

In Panadas data frame, there is an option to preserve the NAN as key = None

Is there a way to preserve the Nan in PySpark DF

Comment: NaN is actually None. So it does not actually exist (It is not an object). Why don't you fill the values with something like `"NULL"` for it to be an indication of null values as well?

Comment: Thanks ... This is what I actually did.  .na.fill("").coalesce(1).  This works fine.